# How to create seamless and coherent voxel terrain using simplex noise 2D?

Tags: c++, voxels, unreal-4

[image]

I'm using the simplex noise 2d plugin for unreal engine 4, which can also be understood by most programmers.
I have already implemented chunk generation and dual-chunk noise elevation.
However, each chunk has a unique heightmap and this results in jagged voxel terrains.
Pseudo code:

```
//Chunk.cpp
for(int chunkWidth = 0; chunkWidth <= 10; chunkWidth++){
   for(int chunkHeight = 0; chunkHeight <= 10; chunkHeight++){
      noiseX = ((chunkWidth / 10) - 0.5) * Frequency;
      noiseY = ((chunkHeight / 10) - 0.5) * Frequency;
      Elevation = SimplexNoise2D(noiseX, noiseY) * 100;
      ChunkLoc = getActorLocation(self);
      SpawnMeshAtLoc(ChunkLoc.x + chunkWidth, ChunkLoc.y + chunkHeight, Elevation);
   }
}
```

I have another variable available: chunk2DCoord(2D vector coordinate for each chunk)

Comment: What is your expected result? What is "jagged" vs "non-jagged"?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by changing the parameters of this function.
The iteration caused this problem. The x and y values of the noise function should encompass the values of a voxel's world position.

USimplexNoise::SimplexNoise2D(VoxelWorldLocation.x, VoxelWorldLocation.y);